# несоответствие результата adf.test() с наблюдением

Tags: r, статистика, rstudio

Приведенный код выполняет линейную комбинацию двух временный рядов, оценку коинтеграции с помощью функции adf.test() и строит график результата линейной комбинации с учетом коэфф. линейной регрессии. При выполнении примера кода p-value получается равный 0,0151223. График линейной комбинации представлен на прикрепленном изображении.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: график и значение p-value явно не соответствуют друг другу, так как стационарный временной ряд с значением p-value = 0.015 будет приближен к идеальной синусоиде, а на графике линейной комбинации мы видим далеко не идеальную синусоиду. Откуда тогда берется такое маленькое значение p-value?[image: график остатков регрессии исходных рядов]

```
library(tseries)
library(timeDate)
stock1=get.hist.quote(instrument = "OMC", start = "2005-01-01", end = "2020-10-01", quote = "AdjClose", retclass = "zoo", quiet = TRUE, drop = FALSE)
stock2=get.hist.quote(instrument = "IPG", start = "2005-01-01", end = "2020-10-01", quote = "AdjClose", retclass = "zoo", quiet = TRUE, drop = FALSE)
regression=lm(stock1$Adjusted~stock2$Adjusted)
p.value=adf.test(regression$residuals)$p.value
beta=regression$coefficients
n=beta[2:2]
spread=stock1-n*stock2
plot(spread)
```

[image: график линейной комбинации]

Answer (score 0):

Пытаюсь понять ваш ход мысли, но как-то не получается.

Во-первых, значение p-value ничего не может говорить об исходных рядах. p-value -  это показатель доверия к нуль-гипотезе, и только. И уж тем более о приближении стационарного ряда к синусоиде он точно говорить не может.

Нулевая гипотеза для ADF-теста  это гипотеза о наличии единичного корня, т.е. о нестационарности ряда. Малое значение p-value говорит о том, что ряд можно считать стационарным (отвергнута гипотеза о наличии единичного корня).

В вашем случае вы проверяете стационарность ряда, который построен как регрессионная модель. Причем - линейная!

Ваша переменная spread никакого отношения к регрессионной модели (той самой ADF которой вы считали) отношения не имеет.

Ввиду этого хаоса, как-то интерпретировать ваши результаты (даже не понятно какие) практически невозможно.

Comment: На коинтеграцию проверялся рад остатков регрессии, а насколько мне известно в линейной регрессии происходит такая же комбинация как и в переменной spread, поэтому я принял переменную spread идентичной остаткам регрессии. Для уточнения прикрепляю график остатков регрессии.    Тогда как проверить более точно коинтеграцию рядов, без использования "доверия" к нуль-гипотезе?

Comment: Смотрим определение из Википедии: "Коинтеграция — свойство нескольких нестационарных (интегрированных) временных рядов, заключающееся в существовании некоторой их стационарной линейной комбинации".   По сути  коинтеграция — это регрессия нестационарных рядов. Как можно проверить коинтеграцию ряда (одного!!!!) остатка? Вы часом не путаете коинтеграцию и автокорреляцию (остатков)?

Comment: нет нет, регрессия проводит линейную комбинацию двух временных рядов (такую же как в переменной spread) и остатки регрессии являются линейной комбинацией первоначальных рядов, по крайней мере это можно отметить взглянув на графики , что я предоставил

Comment: То в чем вы увидели несоответствие?  Какое значение дал ваш ADF-тест мы не знаем.  Но судя по его p-value этого теста, можно принять гипотезу стационарности остатков. (Это можно заподозрить даже глядя на ваш график).   Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: я написал, что мой тест дал значение 0,0151. а вопрос заключается в том, почему  пивелью такое маленькое - меньше 5% (вероятности того, что ряд нестационарен). Обьективно, по графику, нельзя сказать, что этот ряд стационарен

Comment: На глаз -  это не объективно, а очень даже субъективно. А вот тест - это как раз вполне себе объективно.

Answer (score 0):

Низкий p-value не имеет отношение к идеальной синусоиде. Он только означает что временной ряд стационарный, что говорит о его линейной периодичности.
Дополнение: если вы сомневаетесь в стационарности этого временного ряда - воспользуйтесь kpss.test() (в отличии от adf.test() низкий p-value говорит о его НЕстацинорности)
Если результаты двух тестов покажут расхождения то проверяйте правильность временного ряда